# The definition of Borel sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the text of Probability Essentials by J.Jacod & P.Protter, a theorem:

The Borel $ \sigma $- algebra of $R $ is generated by intervals of the form $(-\infty,a ]$, where $a \in Q$.

As far as I've known the Borel sigma algebra is generated by all open subsets of $R$, which surely contains sets like (x, y), here x is irrational. So my question is how can 'a', in theorem, a rational generate such set (x, y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x,y) = \displaystyle\bigcup_{\substack{a,b\in\mathbb{Q} \\ x<a<b<y}} (a,b)$.

Comment: could you please explain it a bit in detail?

Comment: @DylanZhu Filling in more details: $(a,b'] = (-\infty,b'] \cap (-\infty,a']^c$, and $(a,b) = \cup_{b'\in\mathbb{Q}, b'<b} (a,b']$.  Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: yeah, i think i still dont know how can you make sure that b is close enough to y, that there wont be other irrationals between them...

Comment: The rationals are dense.  For any $(x,x+\epsilon)$, pick $n > 1/\epsilon$, then some rational $t/n$ must land in there.